# Gene list of developmental regulators using useMart?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am trying to fish out a list of developmental regulators from the mouse genome using mart. So far, I uploaded the dataset as follows:

```
martDB <- useMart('ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL',dataset='mmusculus_gene_ensembl',
                              host="may2012.archive.ensembl.org")
```

Now, I am looking for a way to parse all of these genes and find the ones that are linked to development (or something analogous).
Thanks for any help!

Comment: you should ask biostars.org

Comment: Did you really **upload** the dataset? Which information do you have from these data set? Did you try linking it to the gene ontologies or metabolic pathways?